# Node.js 0.4.10. http get( ) request " ETIMEDOUT Connection timed out " frequently

Tags: node.js

Recently, I sank into the issue on  "ETIMEDOUT  Connection timed out".
My application just use the  get() method to download files and data from the remote server.
during the downloading(I mean I have downloaded some files but not completely), I just get the  "ETIMEDOUT  Connection timed out". It's a bug of node.js?  I use node.js 0.4.10.  Because of the ETIMEDOUT, I cannot download files completely.

```
http = require('http');
client_req = http.get(...)//

//...
client_req.on('error', callback(err){...})/*When ETIMEDOUT, I get the error 
message: ETIMEDOUT  Connection timed out  here.*/
```

Comment: The error is what it's named, a timeout. Not necessarily a node.js bug. Do you get timeouts when you use curl with the same url?

Comment: Hi， I am not sure about curl. But as I descriped above. For example, I have 10 files to download from the same connection. I always have already downloaded  5 or 9 files, then , ETIMEDOUT Connection timed out.  I don't know why. These days I try to read the source code of node.js to solve this problem. But I am failed. And I could not find a correct to print the log in the lib/http.js  lib/net.js to locat who emit the ETIMEDOUT error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Node.js bug, most probably the url cannot be reached anymore, that's why you get a timeout. As @DeaDEnD suggested, do a curl  to see if you get a timeout also with cURL.

Comment: Hi， I am not sure about it. how about the node.js http client request quene? I find that there is maxsockets = 5 in the http.js. Because that my application must get() hundreds of times at one time.

Comment: You can set agent: false to override that: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.get

Comment: set the agent: false. But the "ETIMEDOUT Connection timed out"  sometime  comes again.

Comment: Did you curl the url a few times? Are you sure that site doesn't often timeout?

Comment: um, I will test the url use curl right now. Because of the urls are not always the same. So it will take a long time.

Comment: I just write a shell script curl  10,000 times to the server url. nothing happend. I don't get any timed out error. oops...